# No such file or directory -- Building an RPM with CPACK using custom spec file

Tags: cmake, rpm, rpm-spec, cpack

I'm trying to build an RPM with CPACK using my own .spec file.  In following the [tutorial from here](https://schneide.wordpress.com/2013/02/11/build-a-rpm-package-using-cmake/).

I'm getting an error when building the RPM:

```
No such file or directory
```

It has to do with the Source0 line in the .spec file

I've got this in my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
CONFIGURE_FILE("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/my_project.spec.in" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/my_project.spec" @ONLY IMMEDIATE)
SET(CPACK_RPM_USER_BINARY_SPECFILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/my_project.spec")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_RELEASE 2)
INCLUDE(CPack)
```

This works and generates a .spec file.  In my .spec.in file, it's got:

```
Buildroot:  @CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR@/_CPack_Packages/Linux/RPM/@CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME@

Name:       @CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME@
Version:    @CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION@
Release:    @CPACK_PACKAGE_RELEASE@%{dist}
Summary:    Blah blah

Vendor:         @CPACK_PACKAGE_VENDOR@

License:        MIT
Source0:        https://github.com/me/%{name}/archive/%{version}.tar.gz

BuildRequires:  gcc, make, cmake
BuildRequires:  doxygen, graphviz, doxygen-latex

%description
<SNIPPED>
```

Then I get rhe error

```
CPackRPM:Debug: *** error: File /home/me/projects/my_project/build/_CPack_Packages/Linux/RPM/SOURCES/1.0.0.0.tar.gz: No such file or directory
```

That error is due to the Source0 line I imagine.

If I do this instead, I get a little different error:

```
CPackRPM:Debug: *** error: File /home/me/projects/my_project/build/_CPack_Packages/Linux/RPM/SOURCES/my_project: No such file or directory
```

And somewhat related, this doesn't seem to generate an SRPM either. I need one of those to submit to Fedora for inclusion in package db.

Comment: For now, I've worked around this by not using CPack directly, but instead composing a target in the CMakeLists.txt file that creates the SRPM and RPM.  (`make srpm` and `make rpm`)  I'll leave the question open in case anyone knows a way to do it with CPack

Comment: I was in the same boat, but I found [this](https://www.redhat.com/archives/rpm-list/2007-February/msg00060.html) which led me to remove `%setup` from my `%prep` section. Also, [this](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/tree/12d5ccd10a451301bf3cbdefe8fde744bf6c9467/Tests/RunCMake/CPack/tests/CUSTOM_BINARY_SPEC_FILE) test directly from CMake's repository is helpful in understanding how to use a custom spec file (e.g.: using `configure_file` is no longer required as the `CPACK_RPM_ROUTER_USER_BINARY_SPECFILE` directive accepts `.spec.in` templates).

Comment: `CPACK_RPM_<component>_USER_BINARY_SPECFILE` in above comment.